# Delete Record with related records

Tags: mysql, django

So I setup a user_profile model and related it back to the auth_user as per lots of posts on here.  Works great: however, when I go to delete a user, on production, it doesn't list the related profile for deletion, so then throws a database error `a foreign key constraint fails`.

On my develpment system; it works fine; in the admin it shows that it will delete the user and related user_profile record.

I move it to my production system (same setup, just via nginx and uwsgi) and it fails :(

What code do you need to see to help me debug/solve this?

Any ideas? i'm baffled... databases are identical (export from dev, import to prod machine).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solved my own issue;

Because I had created the profile in a new application, i forgot to add it on the production server settings.py file.  once I did that, it worked.

Strange part is; creating a user, inline forms worked fine/great. I could access, saved and display a user's profile even though the application was not "installed".  Strange.

Comment: it could be the parent table restricted the cascading deletion. (on delete = restrict)

Comment: yes, that is the default setting for django (and puts that in the mysql database), but django then warns you in the admin that it will also remove related objects. It wasn't in my case until i added the app to the 'install apps' in settings. yet I was still able to use the objects\